# Calculate mean by group among observation without NA

Tags: r, dplyr

Updated:

Hi! I have a data like this.

```
structure(list(V1QB10 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2), V1QB12A = c(2, 
1, 2, 3, NA, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2), V1QB12B = c(NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2), V1QB12C = c(NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), sum = c(NA, 
4, 6, 7, NA, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is how the data looks like:

```
 V1QB10 V1QB12A V1QB12B V1QB12C sum
1       1       2      NA      NA  NA
2       1       1       2       1   4
3       1       2       2       2   6
4       2       3       2       2   7
5       1      NA       2       2  NA
6       3       2       1       1   4
7       3       2       2       2   6
8       1       3       2       2   7
9       4       2       2       2   6
10      2       2       2       2   6
```

Variable "sum" is the sum of "V1QB12*".
Now I'm trying to calculate the mean of the "sum" by "V1QB10":

```
dt %>%
  group_by(V1QB10) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n=n(), mean=mean(sum), sd=sd(sum)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

I'm expect the calculation like:

for V1QB10==1, the n is 3 (remove 2 observations with NA in "V1QB12*"), and sum up the "sum": 4+6+7=17, then calculate the mean: 17/3, and the sd.

But I found that I keep getting mean of 17/5. Trying to replace the code with `n=n(V1QB12A)` also didn't work.
Maybe I'm overthinking this problem. How I'm gonna do to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your expected output for this example?

Comment: V1QB10 has one line with value 4, where sum is 6. Its mean sum is therefore also 6, but sd is undefined for vectors with length one. Shorter equivalent: `sd(6)` = NA

Comment: @RonakShah Hi I just edited the question.

Comment: @JonSpring  Hi! I didn't make my question clear enough. I just edited it again.

Comment: Just add `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean` to ignore the `NA` values ? `mean=mean(sum, na.rm. =TRUE)`

Comment: Surely this must be a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works!! (just a bit confusing when I see the count is 5 but the mean is actually calculated among 3 observations hahahahahha!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I follow what you're looking for, but the dplyr package has a nifty `drop_na()` function that will remove the NA's if you use it like this:

```
dt <- dt %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sum=rowSums(dplyr::select(., contains("V1QB12")), na.rm=T))

dt %>%
  group_by(V1QB10) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n=n(), mean=mean(sum), sd=sd(sum)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Result:

```
 V1QB10 n     mean        sd
1      1 3 5.666667 1.5275252
2      2 2 6.500000 0.7071068
3      3 2 5.000000 1.4142136
4      4 1 6.000000        NA
```

Comment: Thank you so mcuh! This is definitely a solution. But because I also have other variables in the dataset, for drop_na() I will need to create a subset (I know this is not difficult). I'm thinking if there is a way to do that without permanently drop any observation from the dataset